# Android 13 Custom Launcher application is not launched via Appium 2.0

Tags: appium-android, android-uiautomator, android-13

We are having an Custom App launcher application(Similar like Samsung One ui) in our company and when I try to run the Automation execution for the Launcher app am getting this error “**Activity used to start app doesn’t exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity**”.

The activityName and packageName is correct and it works well on Android 11,10,9 devices. Someone help on the same. Thanks

Tried setting the launcher App as default manually and executed the scripts. still it failed to detect

Answer (score 0):

Android 13 needs a different Intent category for apps which don´t have their own app launcher.
Try changing intent in desired capabilities from `"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` to `"android.intent.category.INFO"`

```
desired_cap = {
    "appium:deviceName": device_name,
    "appium:app": path_to_apk,
    "appium:appPackage": app_package,
    "appium:appActivity":app_activity,
    "appium:intentCategory": "android.intent.category.INFO",
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked for me when i Provided "capability.setCapability("intentCategory","android.intent.category.HOME");"